# How to calculate custom car prices (with the condition, that the same component is not added twice to the same car)

Tags: c#, linq, oop, generics, console-application

I have a console app that calculates the price of a car. The basic configuration costs $ 1000 and can be expanded with an additional 6 options (can found in the comments in the code). Each machine has a unique id. The machine can be painted in one or several colors.

**NOTE!** Additional options must be selected (you simply cannot calculate the basic configuration without options). It is not allowed to repeat the same component twice for the same car.

**Input:** *ID* (1-st pos) *1 of 6 options* (2-nd pos) ... to *-1*.

**Output:** sorted car prices in ascending order of car ids ... to *-1*

See more info in here: [Calculation price table for ids and options (for custom auto configuration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWFks.png)

My solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CarFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // input numbers
            var numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            // step
            int i = 0;

            List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();

            // check while step not equils termination number
            while (numbers[i] != -1)
            {
                // check if value == null
                // then, create an item with unique ID
                // and add one or more options for car configuration
                if (cars.Where(x => x.id == numbers[i]).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                {
                    Car c = new Car();
                    c.id = numbers[i];
                    c.cDetails[numbers[i + 1] - 1] = true;
                    cars.Add(c);
                }
                else
                {
                    // if not null
                    Car c = cars.Where(x => x.id == numbers[i]).FirstOrDefault();
                    c.cDetails[numbers[i + 1] - 1] = true;
                }

                i += 2; // increase step by 2
            }

            // sorting car prices in ascending order of car ids
            var sortedCarId = from x in cars orderby x.id select x;

            foreach (var carPrice in sortedCarId)
            {
                Console.Write(carPrice.GetCarPrice() + " ");
            }
            Console.Write(-1);
        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        public int id;
        public bool[] cDetails = new bool[6];

        // calculate the cost of each car with custom configuration
        public int GetCarPrice()
        {
            int[] el = new int[6];
            el[0] = Convert.ToInt32(cDetails[0]) * 150;     // Air conditioning for $150
            el[1] = Convert.ToInt32(cDetails[1]) * 50;      // Power windows for $50
            el[2] = Convert.ToInt32(cDetails[2]) * 125;     // Parking assistance for $125
            el[3] = Convert.ToInt32(cDetails[3]) * 25;      // Black paint for $25
            el[4] = Convert.ToInt32(cDetails[4]) * 20;      // Green paint for $20
            el[5] = Convert.ToInt32(cDetails[5]) * 30;      // Pink paint for $30

            // basic car configuration costs $1000 + sum of options
            return el.Sum() + 1000;
        }
    }
}

// Input:   1 2 1 1 2 2 1 5 2 5 3 1 3 6 2 4 3 3 5 1 -1
// Output:  1220 1095 1305 1150 -1
```

The program counts well, but not all tests pass: only 6 / 10.
I have 4 cases - WRONG RESULT.

Why is this code not passing all test-cases? I have no idea. Help anyone, algorithm or code) Thanks everyone!

Comment: What test fails?  In what way does it fail?  It sounds like this would be a great opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with the use of a debugger, which you can use to step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the runtime values and behavior.  When you do that, which line of code first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values of the variables at that time?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: Tests can return only 3 answer options: OK, WRONG RESULT and TIMED OUT. I have no source code of tests. I just know that everything went right or wrong. I used a debugger, but I have no idea where errors may occur.

Comment: That's pretty unfortunate, because if you don't (can't) know what the tests are actually testing then there isn't much you or anybody can do to correct the code.  You can't be expected to meet a specification that's being kept a mystery from you.

Comment: Yes David, this is very bad. It's out of my hands.
This task is from the OOP section. Perhaps they didn’t like some pieces of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code solution on C#, 10/10

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CarFactory
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

            Console.Write(String.Join(" ", BlackBox(numbers)) + " " + -1);
        }

        private static int[] BlackBox(int[] numbers)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> carPrices = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            carPrices.Add(0, 0);
            carPrices.Add(1, 150);
            carPrices.Add(2, 50);
            carPrices.Add(3, 125);
            carPrices.Add(4, 25);
            carPrices.Add(5, 20);
            carPrices.Add(6, 30);

            Dictionary<int, int> totals = new Dictionary<int, int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i += 2)
            {
                int key = numbers[i];

                if (key == -1)
                    break;

                int priceKey = numbers[i + 1];

                if (totals.ContainsKey(key))
                    totals[key] += carPrices[priceKey];
                else
                    totals[key] = carPrices[priceKey];
            }
            return new SortedDictionary<int, int>(totals)
                .Select(e => 1000 + e.Value)
                .TakeWhile(x => x != -1)
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```